# Excel VBA compare strings with spaces, percentage signs, and commas

Tags: vba, excel, string-comparison

**Update:** I copy and pasted my example html file from here into a new file to make sure people could test with it, and then my code worked! I'm thinking this is an encoding issue because the original file was auto-generated from a Linux machine. I've tried saving a new file and reopening that one from the script, but that didn't work. I'm hoping I could still solve this using only one VBA macro by either somehow saving a new file and using the data in that one or making sure the encoding matches.

---

I can't seem to compare the following string correctly:

```
line, %
```

I've been trying to use the **StrComp** function and just using an **equal** sign, but both have not worked. I also used the **Trim** function on the strings I'm comparing to make sure there's no whitespace on either ends. I can trace through the debugger and see that the values I'm comparing are both "line, %", but the expression never evaluates to true.

Do any of the characters in this string cause me to have to do something special in order for a comparison to work?

**Edit:** This does work (I made a typo in my last edit):

```
Dim percentString As String
percentString = "line, %"

Dim test As String
test = percentString
If StrComp(percentString, test) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "They are equal"
End If
```

**However, I'm reading input from an html file, and that is not working. See below for code you can try.**

Maybe it has to do with **charset=ISO-8859-1** in the html input? Would the character set matter? Here is what is at the beginning: `<HTML><HEAD><META CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"/>`

**Here is an example you can try**

testFile.html

```
<HTML><HEAD><META CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"/><TITLE>title</TITLE><STYLE> 

TABLE,TD,TH {border-style:solid; border-color:black;} TD,TH {background:white;margin:0;line-height:100%;padding-

left:0.5em;padding-right:0.5em;} TD {border-width:0 1px 0 0;} TH {border-width:1px 1px 1px 0;} TR TD.h {color:red;} TABLE 

{border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;border-width:0 0 1px 1px;} P,H1,H2,H3,TH {font-family:verdana,arial,sans-

serif;font-size:10pt;} TD {font-family:courier,monospace;font-size:10pt;} TABLE.hdft {border-spacing:0;border-

collapse:collapse;border-style:none;} TABLE.hdft TH,TABLE.hdft TD {border-style:none;line-height:normal;} TABLE.hdft 

TH.tl,TABLE.hdft TD.tl {background:#6699CC;color:white;} TABLE.hdft TD.nv {background:#6633DD;color:white;} .nv A:link 

{color:white;} .nv A:visited {color:white;} .nv A:active {color:yellow;} TABLE.hdft A:link {color:white;} TABLE.hdft 

A:visited {color:white;} TABLE.hdft A:active {color:yellow;} .in {color:#356085;} TABLE.s TD {padding-left:0.25em;padding-

right:0.25em;} TABLE.s TD.l {padding-left:0.25em;padding-right:0.25em;text-align:right;background:#F0F0F0;} TABLE.s TR.z TD 

{background:#FF9999;} TABLE.s TR.p TD {background:#FFFF88;} TABLE.s TR.c TD {background:#CCFFCC;} A:link 

{color:#0000EE;text-decoration:none;} A:visited {color:#0000EE;text-decoration:none;} A:hover {color:#0000EE;text-

decoration:underline;} TABLE.cn {border-width:0 0 1px 0;} TABLE.s {border-width:1px 0 1px 1px;} TD.h {color:red;border-

width:0 1px 0 0;} TD.f {border-width:0 1px 0 1px;} TD.hf {color:red;border-width:0 1px 0 1px;} TH.f {border-width:1px 1px 

1px 1px;} TR.cis TD {background:#F0F0F0;} TR.cis TD {border-width:1px 1px 1px 0;} TR.cis TD.h {color:red;border-width:1px 

1px 1px 0;} TR.cis TD.f {border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px;} TR.cis TD.hf {color:red;border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px;} TD.b 

{border-style:none;background:transparent;line-height:50%;}  TD.bt {border-width:1px 0 0 0;background:transparent;line-

height:50%;} TR.o TD {background:#F0F0F0;}TABLE.it {border-style:none;}TABLE.it TD,TABLE.it TH {border-style:none;}

</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><TABLECELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%"><TR><TH>Report</TH></TR><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE><H2></H2><TABLE 

CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%"><TR><TH>line, %</TH></TR><TR><TD>Name</TD></TR></TABLE><H3></H3><TABLE CELLSPACING="0" 

WIDTH="100%"><TR><TH>line, %</TH></TR><TR><TD>test</TD></TR></TABLE><P></P><TABLE CELLSPACING="0" 

WIDTH="100%"><TR><TD></TD></TR><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

**Use this VBA code and make small modifications to specify where testFile.html is**.

```
Option Explicit
Sub percent()

    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFile = "testFile.html"

    Dim percentString As String
    percentString = CStr("line, %")

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "path\to\testFile" & MyFile

    Dim stringVal As String
    Dim val As Variant
    Set ws = Worksheets("testFile")
    For Each val In ws.UsedRange.Value
        stringVal = CStr(val)
        stringVal = Replace(stringVal, vbLf, "")
        stringVal = Replace(stringVal, vbTab, "")
        stringVal = Trim(Application.Clean(stringVal))
        percentString = Replace(percentString, vbLf, "")
        percentString = Replace(percentString, vbTab, "")
        percentString = Trim(Application.Clean(percentString))
        Dim res As Integer
        res = StrComp(stringVal, percentString)
        If res = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Found the percent string"
        End If
    Next val
    Workbooks(MyFile).Close
End Sub
```

Comment: how is the string getting assigned to your variable for comparison?  I have did a simple test and "line, %" didn't have any problems when I compared it using various methods...

Comment: @sous2817 I'm using **Workbooks.Open** to open an **html** file. Then I get the sheet and use a For Each loop to iterate through theSheet.UsedRange.Value

Comment: Ok, my guess is some junk / hidden characters are coming in because of  HTML.  Try Dan's suggestion below and see if it helps...

Comment: It would be helpful also if you could post a sample of your data somewhere for us to try different things.

Comment: @sous2817 Check out my edit. Even if I set them equal, I still can't get an **if** statement to evaluate to true.

Comment: try comparing percentString to test and not testString...this is a reason to use Option Explicit (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)

Comment: @sous2817 Thanks, I actually made a typo in my example program, but I'm still using Option Explicit now.

Comment: @sous2817 I added html input that you can copy and paste into a file called testFile.html, and I gave you the VBA code to open it and try to get that comparison to be true.

Comment: I'll take a stab at it tonight and let you know what I can come up with.

Comment: @sous2817 Thanks! Also, I just copy and pasted my example html file from here into a new file to make sure you would be able to use it just fine, and now the code works. I'm thinking this is an enocding issue because the original file was auto-generated from a Linux machine. I'm wondering if from VBA I could save off the file as a new one and open that one, but so far that isn't working.

Comment: I think it's something off on your end.  I used your test file and your code and I found the string w/o making any modifications to either the code or the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was an encoding problem. Basically, an **Â** character showed up in the debugger *only after* I made a script that changed all the **line, %** lines into something else. Therefore, the following got rid of the **Â** character, and this character is why I couldn't get the comparison to evaluate to true:

```
stringVal = Replace(stringVal, Chr(194), vbNullString)
```

Sorry to all of those who tried to help. Turns out this kind of question would have only been useful to try to answer if I could have uploaded the input file itself so the encoding would have stayed.

Answer (score 0):

When I have run into this problem in the past I have done two things:

1) See what the string is by creating a cell that has something like:

```
B1= "|" & A1 & "|"
```

I use this on both cells to see if there is anything strange.  Sometimes there are tabs or new lines that don't show up.

2) I substitute out strange things.  If you find a new line you can use find replace to get rid of it all together or you can do a substitute with substr().

Hope this helps a bit.  If you post the results from 1 I may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks, I put the "|" in the cells, and there was no whitespace. I also tried using the following functions to get rid of any characters: `percentString = Replace(percentString, vbLf, "")
         percentString = Replace(percentString, vbTab, "")
         percentString = Trim(Application.Clean(percentString))`

Answer (score 0):

The `StrComp` function returns 0 if the strings are equal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx

Kind regards.